# how to combine unicode date and time

Tags: python, date, unicode, time

```
start_date = 03/19/2014 - Wednesday 
start_time = 08:00 AM
```

Both are Unicode strings.

I am getting output like above.

Now i want to combines these date and time. My result should be like

```
03/19/2014 08:AM
```

How to do this in Python.

Comment: Did you try adding them?

Comment: Those are not valid python statements. What it is then?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
>>> start_date = '03/19/2014 - Wednesday'
>>> start_time = '08:00 AM'
>>> ' '.join(start_date.split(' - ')[:1] + [start_time])
'03/19/2014 08:00 AM'
```

Or simply:

```
>>> start_date.split(' - ')[0] + ' ' + start_time
'03/19/2014 08:00 AM'
```